# Is there any performance benefit of using Arrays.stream() over iterating on an array?

Tags: enums, java-8, java-stream

I need to iterate on all the enum values, check if they were used to construct an int (called `input`) and if so, add them to a Set (called `usefulEnums`). I can either use streams API or iterate over all the enums to do this task. Is there any benefit of using `Arrays.stream()` over the traditional approach of iterating over the `values()` array?

```
   enum TestEnum { VALUE1, VALUE2, VALUE3 };

   Set<TestEnum> usefulEnums = new HashSet<>();

   Arrays.stream(TestEnum.values())
            .filter(t -> (input & t.getValue()) != 0)
            .forEach(usefulEnums::add);

    for (TestEnum t : TestEnum.values()) {
        if ((input & t.getValue()) != 0) {
            usefulEnums.add(t);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this short operation the `for loop` is going to be faster (nano-seconds faster), but to me the stream operation is `more verbose`, it tells exactly what is being done here. It's like reading diagonally.

Also you could collect directly to a `HashSet`:

```
Arrays.stream(TestEnum.values())
        .filter(t -> (input & t.getValue()) != 0)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Valuable input from Holger as usual makes this even nicer:

```
EnumSet<TestEnum> filtered = EnumSet.allOf(TestEnum.class).stream()
            .filter(t -> (input & t.getValue()) != 0)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(TestEnum.class)));
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)

Comment: In the common case where you just need a `Set`, not a `HashSet` specifically, `Collectors.toSet()` is preferable.

Comment: @Solomonoff's Secret: when the elements are enum constants, like `TestEnum`, it might be preferable to use `Collectors.toCollection(() -> EnumSet.noneOf(TestEnum.class))` instead, though the task of getting all `enum` constants matching a predicate has a simpler straight-forward solution…

Comment: @Holger awesome. I have no idea why I always thought that `EnumSet.noneOf` and `allOf` are immutable.

Comment: @Eugene It's a confusing API. Those methods look like `Collections.emptySet()` and the like. But I'm not sure the API designers had much choice because these factory methods return different classes depending on the number of enum elements of the given type, so a constructor wouldn't suffice. Perhaps `EnumSet.create` would be clearer but it would spoil the consistency between the names `noneOf` and `allOf`.

Comment: @Solomonoff'sSecret absolutely great point about `Collections.emptySet()`. This is why I never even tried to use them as mutable.

Answer (score 5):

If you care for efficiency, you should consider:

```
Set<TestEnum> usefulEnums = EnumSet.allOf(TestEnum.class);
usefulEnums.removeIf(t -> (input & t.getValue()) == 0);
```

Note that when you have to iterate over all `enum` constants of a type, using `EnumSet.allOf(EnumType.class).stream()` avoids the array creation of `EnumType.values()` entirely, however, most `enum` types don’t have enough constants for this to make a difference. Further, the JVM’s optimizer may remove the temporary array creation anyway.

But for this specific task, where the result is supposed to be a `Set<TestEnum>`, using an `EnumSet` instead of a `HashSet` may even improve subsequent operations working with the `Set`. Creating an `EnumSet` holding all constants and removing unintented constants like in the solution above, means just initializing a `long` with `0b111`, followed by clearing the bits of nonmatching elements.

Comment: `means just initializing a long with 0b111` unless you have more then 64 entries, when a `JumboEnumSet` will be used. Good point about `EnumSet.allOf`

Comment: @Eugene: well `0b111` obviously refers the the question’s case of exactly three constants. If the `enum` had `64` constants, it would be `0b1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111_1111` instead, if it had more, there was a `long[]` array, but then, the absence of the much larger `TestEnum[]` could become noticeable, making the advantage of the `EnumSet` even larger.

Comment: @Holger Can you explain `means just initializing a long with 0b111`?

Comment: An `EnumSet` assigns a bit to each `enum` constant and sets it to `1`, if the constant is contained. So for your enumeration, having three constants, it uses a single `long` variable and `EnumSet.allOf` will initialize it to have all three bits set, i.e. `0b111`, which means “all constants are present”. Then, `removeIf` will just clear the bits matching the predicate. So, unlike `HashSet`, no arrays have to be allocated nor filled. In case, your not familiar with it, `0b111` is a [Binary Literal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/binary-literals.html).